# fscanf() != EOF as exit condition of loop exits at the wrong time

Tags: c, loops, file-io, scanf, eof

I'm taking the input from [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4rpp0ph9e5hRFlwd2dCMXhBTzQ/view), which I know contains a series of elements of type:

```
typedef struct{
    char artist[50];
    char title[50];
    int num; //numero traccia
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
} track;
```

but when I take my input with a loop, the program thinks it reaches `EOF` right after the first struct, even though I've found out there are 9 of those elements, and then a bunch of garbage. So in the worst case it should print a bunch of garbage after the 9 tracks, instead it only reads the first and then thinks it hit `EOF`.

At first I had `while(!feof(fp))`, but I read it's really bad code, so I tried the return of `fscanf` as everyone seems to suggest, but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 15

typedef struct {
    char artist[50];
    char title[50];
    int num; 
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
} track;

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/path/album.bin", "rb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    track song[N];    //array of structs

    while (fscanf(fp,"%[^\n] %[^\n] %d %d %d",
                  song[i].artist, song[i].title, &song[i].num,
                  &song[i].minutes, &song[i].seconds) != EOF) { 
        printf("Artist: %s\nTitle: %s\nNum: %d\nLength: %d:%d\n\n",
               song[i].artist, song[i].title, song[i].num,
               song[i].minutes, song[i].seconds);
        ++i;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
Artist: Frank Zappa
Title: Inca Roads
Num: 1
Length: 8:45
```

while it should actually print 8 other tracks of that same format.

Comment: `fscanf` can have other failure modes besides `EOF`!

Comment: Additionally the file you're reading is a binary file and `fscanf` makes sense only on text.

Comment: Aside: check the result of `fscanf` against what you *want* it to be, not what you *don't* want it to be. That is, the number of items scanned.

Comment: Please add a sample text file to the question itself: the link isn't good – oh! it isn't a text file at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what other function do you recommend? `fgetc()`?
@WeatherVane I will, thanks for the input. 
Still, I'm not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: @WeatherVane hexdump starts with `0000000 7246 6e61 206b 615a 7070 0061 0000 0000
0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
`

Comment: Is the format of that file documented anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `fscanf()` to read a binary file, and your is a binary one.

Knowing the binary format of file, you can reproduce the structure and copy it from file using a `fread()`.

Analizying the file we can see that the structure isn't padded, so using a packing attribute we can force the compiler to make the same.

The code then will be the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>    //Include this header to access standard integer types as int32_t
#define N 15

#ifdef (__GNUCC__)
#define PACK  __attribute__((packed))
#else
#define PACK
#pragma pack(1)     //Use this if MS compiler or compatible
#endif

typedef struct
{
    char    artist[50];
    char    title[50];
    int32_t num;      //Note use of int32_t to force the use of 4bytes ints
    int32_t minutes;
    int32_t seconds;
} track PACK;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("/path/album.bin","rb+");
  if(fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error opening file\n");
    return -1;
  }

  int i = 0;
  track song[N];    //array of structs

  // Note that fread returns 1 if a complete structure has been read
  // If the file contains less bytes of the size of the structure,
  // fread() will return 0 ending the input.
  while(fread( &song[i], sizeof(track), 1, fp)) 
  {
    printf("Artist: %s\nTitle: %s\nNum: %d\nLength:%d:%d\n\n",
            song[i].artist, song[i].title, song[i].num,
                             song[i].minutes, song[i].seconds);
    ++i;
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Note the use of the type `int32_t` to force the use of 32bits (4bytes) integers. **This is absolutely mandatory to keep consistent the structure layout on systems where the standard `int` type is <> 32bits**.

Observing the layout of the file we can found a repeating pattern that resembles the structure supplied:

```
Offset  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __________ _
0000:  |c|h|a|r| |a|r|t|i|s|t|[|5|0|]| | | / .... / | | 50bytes
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+----------+-+
0032:  |c|h|a|r| |t|i|t|l|e|[|5|0|]| | | | / .... / | | 50bytes
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+----------+-+
0064:  | | | | |    int num     = 32bits = 4bytes 
       +-+-+-+-+
0068:  | | | | |    int minutes = 32bits = 4bytes
       +-+-+-+-+
006C:  | | | | |    int seconds = 32bits = 4bytes
       +-+-+-+-+

structure size=50+50+4+4+4=112 bytes
```

Observing it we see that the fields are not interleaved by any padding (at least considering the standard sizes for `int32_t`.

On the other hand coding the structure without packing attribute will leave freedom to compiler to eventually add padding which is implementation-dependent, possibly leading to la failure if the memory layout is inconsistent toward the file layout.

Another possibility, to bypass such problems is to **serialize** the input, in this case you'll binary read each field using its length.

Just one more word on use of `size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream )` (see more info here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/). Setting `count=1` and `size=sizeof(track)` means that **`fread()` have to read at least `size` bytes at time per each element and one element only**. If the file reaches end before such number of bytes can be read the function returns 0 elements, that stands for false. If a full element can be read the function returns 1 element read for true.

Last, be aware of endianess. In your file it is a little-endian format, if your machine is big-endian swap bytes of `int` members of the structure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you did there. How do you know that the structure isn't padded? Opening the file displays a bunch of \00 (what is that?) and hexdump -C prints the names and artist and then a bunch of dots, which makes me think it is padded, since the data aren't contiguous. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: Dear pirate looking at your structure we count 2 string members, each 50 bytes wide, then 3 `int` that are 32 bits or 4 bytes each. Simply adding you have 50*2+4*3=112 bytes each record. There is no padding because there are no unused spaces between fields. Every 112bytes in the file the whole structure restarts. You can use an hex editor to check file inside. The zeros you see **are paddings, but of the single structure member, not of the structure itself**. Moreover in the last 2 records the member is ...

Comment: filled with rubbish. But you don't have to care because interesting data stops at first zero byte (end for C strings). On the other hand may even happen that the 3 numeric fields are shorter of 32bits and the structure padded on a 32 bits boundary, but even in this case the system still work unless the padding not contains data different from zeros (in this case you can mask them). Anyway you **must use a packed structure** because any other type could not respect the structure layout on file (how padding happen is compiler dependent). So for a good reverse-engineering you have to ...

Comment: carefully observe, try and study a little bit more C language. Buona Fortuna ;-)

Comment: You do not need any padding, the structure is (believe or not) naturally packed. Most notably `int32_t` is necessarily at most 4-byte aligned.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. It is true that the 4bytes is a natural alignment on almost all systems, but may happen that on a very rare system (embedded or DSP) this can't fit. So just in case... I would prefer to force packing ;-)

Comment: @Frankie_C well, if there is embedded DSP with random char size, on which you're trying to read **both** chars from this *file* **and** `int32_t`s you've got a **biiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiig** problem.

Comment: In any case it necessarily follows that unless the compiler is adding *unnecessary* padding then a struct that has these members is always naturally aligned ;) including your CHAR_BIT 16 DSPs

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes you're right :-D with a pure DSP will be very hard :-D

Comment: I.e. what I mean is that if the characters like `A` are supposed to be one `char`, then how come it can read the `int32_t` properly` if `CHAR_BIT` is say 16.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I understood. I agree The code can't apply on a machine which `char` isn't 8 bits (as per the symbol `CHAR_BIT` provided for the C standard). It should work for others (ARM cortex with DSP should comply).

Answer (score 1):

The interesting thing here is not so much that the program emits only one record: that happens because there are no newlines in the (binary) file, so an attempt is made to consume the entire file contents to handle the first `%[^\n]` directive of the format, the first time `fscanf` is called.

No, the interesting thing is that the one record it emits appears sensible despite the read going horribly wrong.  That is, since there is no newline within the first 50 characters, scanning the first field overruns the bounds of array `song[0].artist`, producing undefined behavior.

Indulging in a bit of speculation about the manifestation of that UB, the result appears to have been as if the program just wrote all the bytes of the file into the representation of the `song` array (which is long enough to accommodate them), and that the layout of the `track` structure happens to match the binary format of the file (which is not that surprising).  As a result, all the fields of the first track seem to have been properly filled.

Furthermore, the details of the track structure are such that it is unlikely to be laid out with any trailing (or internal) padding, so we might even speculate that printing some other tracks, outside the loop, might result in the expected data, too.

Interestingly enough, on a system that has the same endianness and the same conventions for structure layout as the one with which the file was written, and supposing that the structure indeed is laid out without any padding, the simplest correct way of reading the data emulates the above possible characterization of `fscanf`'s UB:

```
// no loop needed if all our assumptions are satisfied
size_t num_songs = fread(song, sizeof(song[0]), N, fp);
```

That just reads the whole file (up to `N` tracks) straight into the representation of the array.  You might then loop just to print the results:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_songs; i++) {
    printf("Artist: %s\nTitle: %s\nNum: %d\nLength: %d:%d\n\n",
            song[i].artist, song[i].title, song[i].num, song[i].minutes,
            song[i].seconds);
}
```

That happens to work for me.

Comment: There's no need to put `song[0]` in parentheses. `sizeof` is like an unary operator determining the size of the object operated on. Because we often put a cast there it looks like a function, for example `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: Yes, @thebusybee, `sizeof` is an operator.  The parentheses I've used with it in this case are not obligatory.  But that is not one of the issues I wanted to get into with the OP, who is almost certainly used to seeing the parentheses.

Comment: That's right, its just that I'd like to see good code in examples.

Comment: Although the parentheses  *can* be omitted, @thebusybee, they are so idiomatic that I altogether reject the proposition that doing so would make the code better in any way that matters to me.

Comment: Sigh... ;-) No offend.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't ask a specific question I'll try to get you in the right direction.

The file you linked is a binary file containing records of `struct track`. So you can't read it with `fscanf()`. You can use `fread()` as a standard alternative; please read its documentation for details how to use it and what it returns. Consider endianness if the file is written on one computer and read on a different computer.

The other obvious problem was mentioned in the comments: The family of `scanf()` function returns the number of successfully scanned fields. If there is an error it will return an `int` value less than expected.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you apparently try to read binary data, see [busybee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11294831/the-busybee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57530305/1312382) for this issue (fscanf is not applicable on binary data!).

Second (now let's assume the data would have been stored in a *text* file), [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) doesn't return the file stream state, but the number of arguments successfully scanned, so you should check for equality on number of format parameters, i. e. `5` in your case.

If you additionally want to check for having reached end of file you can use [`feof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) with the `FILE` pointer as argument. Be aware, though, that reading might fail for [other reasons](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror), too. Your code might then look like this instead:

```
while(fscanf(...) == 5) { /* ... */ }
if(feof(fp))
{
    // you read entire file
}
else
{
    // something went wrong
}
```

Maybe there's yet whitespace only left, so you might need to care for before the final check for having reached end of file.